# Typo3 - for each Element at colPos

Tags: foreach, datatable, typo3, content-management-system

In want to create a table with Image and Headline in a Row.
The Frontent should show me for every Image I uploaded in the Backend an new Row.

I was trying to do that with

```
<f:for each={CONTENT@COLPOS} ...>
...
</f:for>
```

But unfortnatly there is no Array Output.
Can you fix this for me?

Thanks a Lot!

Comment: please explain what you want. what data should result in what output? and what did you try with what results?

Comment: I need to know, how many Pictures are uploades in a specific colPos, to build a loop which puts every Image in a own HTML/CSS box.